# Robotic parts on a beach that assemble

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I'm hoping someone recognizes this short story I read as a boy. The story was about a robotic eyeball that rolled around on a beach until it found a hand. The two parts joined up and wiggled around until they found a leg. They joined the leg and hopped around. That is all I can remember. I would like to know the ending. Does anyone remember this short story or know where it came from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the 1968 book [The Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Man_(novel)) by Ted Hughes.

[The story starts with](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/the-iron-man-by-ted-hughes)

> a gigantic metal robot who appears out of nowhere, crashing onto the
>   beach and shattering into many parts.

The part you've described is this:

> An eye! There it was, blinking at them speechlessly beside a black and
>   white pebble. The seeing hand fitted the eye to the blind hand and now
>   both hands could see.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know The Iron Giant movie was based on a preexisting book. Neat.

Comment: I will look into this. What you describe sounds very much like the story i remember. It is possible that all i had was a few pages from the book, and that may be the reason the story has plagued me all these years.

Comment: @DavidDrysdale I read an excerpt from this in a children's anthology. Maybe you had something similar? My anthology was paperback, roughly letter-sized, ~1" thick, and part of a set of anthologies that all had names like *Over The Rainbow* and *Beyond The Moon*. (I can ask my mother for the actual titles.) They had lots of different stories and poems, all with different illustrators.

Comment: Yes please, that would be nice. I have looked for this for a number of years, and am glad to finally have some mental rest. It is like putting a plug in a hole in my mind that has been leaking.

Comment: @JAB It's quite different from the movie.

Comment: And I came here hoping to be the first one to answer "Bionicle!" Unfortunately those stories started with Onua's hand. Seems like a reference though.

Comment: @user973810 - Yeah - I mean, where's Tony Stark? :-)

Comment: @JAB that's what I thought of when I saw the title, and further in the description